# RGB565 on the Waveshare RP2040 LCD 1.28

Tags: pi-pico, lcd

I'm trying to use the Waveshare LCD 1.28 module found at https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RP2040-LCD-1.28 which based upon their demo python code, the module should support RGB565 for color definitions, however this doesn't appear to be true.

There are a number of color constants defined in the code:

```
self.red   =   0x07E0
self.green =   0x001f
self.blue  =   0xf800
```

But these are not correct for RGB565, instead these should be:

```
self.red   =   0xf800
self.green =   0x07E0
self.blue  =   0x001f
```

The problem is, the incorrect values render correctly on the screen, but this means I can't easily calculate other colors.

Does anyone know how to get this display to use correct RGB565 values? Or some way of correctly calculating colors based on their RGB value to whatever format the screen is using?

I initially thought maybe they are all just shifted and the values are actually BRG, and this works to some degree, but there are some color mixes that don't come out right so it doesn't look as simple as that.

Comment: I know nothing about the hardware you have mentioned BUT the values you mentioned appear to be using a different byte order.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.
I know the display controller has at least three modes.
If it is getting setup in pure RGB565

Update:
The mode is best thought of as BRG565 or B5-G6-R5
Blue Red Green, five blue bits, six red bits,five green bits.
The section in the manual is indexed as RGB565
It is easier to set bits in a binary string so
each field in the 16 bits can be seen.  Start with the
example colors. In another window use python to expand hex to
a string of bits and the fields and order within 16 bits will be apparent.

```
    # Additive Color mixing (not like crayons)
    #self.someghing = 0bBBBBBRRRRRRGGGGG
    #self.red   =   0x07E0
    self.red   =    0b0000001111100000
    self.red1   =   0b0000000000100000
    self.red3   =   0b0000000001100000
    self.red4   =   0b0000000010000000
    #self.green =   0x001f  
    self.green =    0b11111
    #self.blue  =   0xf800
    self.blue  =    0b1111100000000000 
    #self.yellow =  0x7ff  # mix R&G
    self.yellow =   0b11111111111
    self.white =    0xffff  # 0b1111111111111111
```

Explore colors by adding a set of these for each color of interest.
In the demo code

```
    LCD.fill(LCD.blue)
    LCD.show()
    print("Blue")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130537)

Comment: Updated -- should answer and enable progress.